# How to use `Fn` trait with return type of `impl trait` in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to use `Fn` trait whose return type is `impl Trait`.
For example:

```rust
let funcs: [&Fn(&str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str>] =
    [&str::split_whitespace, &str::split_ascii_whitespace];
```

However, this code cannot be compiled with the below error message:

```
`impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
```

How should I do?

Comment: Related doc: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md#limitation-to-freeinherent-functions

Comment: I understood that `impl trait` is now a syntax for unboxed abstraction, thus it cannot be used to abstract different functions, that essentially requires boxed abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

[`str::split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace) and [`str::split_ascii_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_ascii_whitespace) have different return types. You cannot construct an array of varying types. Instead, you can create an array of [boxed trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html). This will perform dynamic dispatch where the specific method called is determined at runtime (instead of static dispatch which is where the specific method version is known at compile-time)

Essentially, the goal is to have all the functions' signatures be:

```
for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&'a str> + 'a>
```

which is a function that takes a `&str` and returns some iterator over `&str`s determined at runtime.

Now, this is where it starts getting messy and I hope someone can suggest a much better way to do this.

One way to get this to work is by creating wrapper functions around `str::split_whitespace` and `str::split_ascii_whitespace` to return a boxed trait instead of their respective `SplitWhitespace` and `SplitAsciiWhitespace` structs. I've used a helper macro to simply wrap the returned value from the function call in a Box

```
macro_rules! boxed_return {
    ($fn_new:ident, $fn:path) => {
        fn $fn_new<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&'a str> + 'a> {
            Box::new($fn(s))
        }
    }
}

boxed_return!(split_whitespace_wrapper, str::split_whitespace);
boxed_return!(split_ascii_whitespace_wrapper, str::split_ascii_whitespace);
```

Then we can simply create the array of splitter functions as follows

```
let funcs = [split_whitespace_wrapper, split_ascii_whitespace_wrapper];
```

Comment: The members of the array need to be trait objects, but they don't need to be _boxed_ - the other answer gives an example. (The inner `Box` is unavoidable, though, as the signatures of the `Fn` trait bounds must be the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that `impl Trait` can only be used in limited places syntactically right now, semantically it only means there will be *one concrete type* in it place. It is not a license for heterogeneous types or dynamic dispatching.

This can be done, but it is becoming unwieldy rather quickly:

```rust
type StrFn<'a> = &'a dyn Fn(&'static str) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'static str>>;

fn main() {
    let f1: StrFn = &|s: &'static str| Box::new(s.split_whitespace());
    let f2: StrFn = &|s: &'static str| Box::new(s.split_ascii_whitespace());
    let fs = vec![f1, f2];

    fs[0]("rust 2020").for_each(|s| println!("{}", s));
}
```

Maybe there are better ways.

Comment: I think you can eliminate the outer box: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81d39fafa8b243bda31a9c13023a319c).

Comment: Thanks. Further, one can extract the creation of the closure into a helper function that (effectively) returns an `impl [trait behind StrFn]`. Unfortunately type aliases don't work for traits, so the function can't name a nice symbolic impl. Still, here it is: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=977a9f55cd8876a79da37ce936e869bb).

Comment: I understood that impl trait is now a syntax for unboxed abstraction, thus it cannot be used to abstract different functions, that essentially requires boxed abstraction.

Comment: Looking at [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64746208/1600898) I learned that you can emulate trait aliases using a new trait with a blanket impl. In case anyone cares, here is the version that has a helper function and still avoids the ugly repetition of `Fn(...)`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5961bcec51b3f704f369c594a9e563c).