# How to make trait aliases?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to give an alias to a function so I don't have to write its signature whenever I implement this trait:

```
type PhySend = Fn();
trait MyTrait {
    fn set_phy_send<F: PhySend>(callback: F);
}
```

But I get:

```
type aliases cannot be used as traits rustc(E0404)
```

So, is it impossible to give aliases to traits / function signatures? It'd be boring to write this signature every time I implement this trait.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because aliases can be any type. Try to define a new trait instead.

```
trait your_function<T> : FnOnce() -> T {}

impl<T, U> your_function<T> for U where U: FnOnce() -> T {}

fn make_tea<F, T>(f: F) -> T
    where F: your_function<T>
{
    f()
}

fn main() {
    make_tea(|| String::new());
}
```

Comment: This is really nice - basically trait aliases can be emulated by a custom trait + blanket impl pair relatively easily.